# Where should a question like this go?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, closed-questions, moderation, not-constructive

[Java-based CMS with RESTful service / API to access content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16751891/java-based-cms-with-restful-service-api-to-access-content)

The question was closed as non-constructive (with a slightly snarky remark), even though the asker clearly has done his homework and specifically says: "For those who might vote to close this question due to "not constructive - As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format." - Would be great if you would suggest where should I post this question (https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ ? or any CMS-focused forum?)"

Where should a question like this be asked?

Comment: The answer to that one is going to be "nowhere within the network" to the best of my knowledge. As was stated by the moderator, it's a shopping question. And we simply don't do those.

Comment: That the OP acknowledges that it's not a good question shouldn't give it protection from being closed. Neither does it mandate people closing it suggest a better place for it.

Comment: It is nice that you are asking _where_ to post such questions, but since the answer would be **not on a Stack Exchange site**, it becomes off-topic... and as a question, doesn't belong on the network either.

Comment: As a bit of a side note, why is it that people expect that we tell them where a question _does_ belong if it is off-topic for the entire network?

Comment: @Oded Let's assume the OP is unaware of it being off-topic for the entire network.

Comment: @Bart - Sure. But why would they think that asking "so where should this be asked" would result in anything? In particular when they options are off-network?

Comment: And I appreciate that I am probably getting a bit "get off my lawn" here ;)

Comment: I'm with @Oded there. The number of times I've closed off totally OT / NC posts as not being suited to our site, only be be met with a "Where where *should* I post it then?" comment. I've just started ignoring those comments otherwise all I'd respond with is 'well how the f*** should I know, I'm only a mod of this site, not of the whole internet'.

Comment: Despite that it looks very good, is well written and seems flawless, it is just another shopping question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Where should a question like this be asked?

The answer to that is simple. Nowhere on the network. As noted by the moderator who closed the question, it's a so-called shopping question asking for recommendations. And those are off-topic.

That the asker did his homework is great. And perhaps the question itself is a valid question to have. But that doesn't make it any more on-topic for the site. Which is kind of unfortunate given the apparent effort by the OP.

That similar questions have been asked before is no guarantee either that the current question is appropriate for the site. Especially if those questions were asked years ago. The site has developed over time and moved on from what at some point were acceptable questions.

There might be other sites more suitable for questions like those, but recommendations for those are off-topic here.

Comment: I guess the difference between "off-topic" (perhaps try another SE site) and "not constructive" (not a Q&A style question) might be a bit too subtle for some :-)